# Coloring by groups using ggscatter

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm trying to color my dots on this plot:

```
q <- ggscatter(ARAL_R, x = "Intl1", y = "Sul1", add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "spearman", xlab = "Intl1 (copies/g)", ylab = "Sul1 (copies/g)") + stat_cor(label.y = 1, label.x.npc = "center") + stat_regline_equation(label.y = 0.5, label.x.npc = "center")
```

[image]

But whenever I add the command `color = "Core"` or `fill = "Core"` (where A is a categorical variable of 5) this happens:

```
q <- ggscatter(ARAL_R, x = "Intl1", y = "Sul1", color = "Core", add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "spearman", xlab = "Intl1 (copies/g)", ylab = "Sul1 (copies/g)") + stat_cor(label.y = 1, label.x.npc = "center") + stat_regline_equation(label.y = 0.5, label.x.npc = "center")
ggpar(q, xscale = "log10", yscale = "log10")
```

[image]

I would like to make it like this:

[image]

But with the spearman's correlation line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when mapping a variable on `color` your data gets split into multiple groups and you get a regression line, correlation coefficient and equation for each group or category of `Core`. To fix that you have to explicitly map on the `group` aes, i.e. use `aes(group = 1)` to treat all obs. as one group which for simplicity or by convention we name `1`. Unfortunately `ggscatter` does not offer this option. That's one of the downsides when using "out-of-the-box" options instead of using vanilla `ggplot2`. But I'm afraid this is the way to go, i.e. add your regression line manually using a `geom_smooth` instead of relying on `ggscatter`:

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `iris`:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

ARAL_R <- iris[3:5]
names(ARAL_R) <- c("Intl1", "Sul1", "Core")

q <- ggscatter(
  ARAL_R,
  x = "Intl1", y = "Sul1", color = "Core",
  xlab = "Intl1 (copies/g)", ylab = "Sul1 (copies/g)"
) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm", color = "black") +
  stat_cor(aes(group = 1), label.y = 1, label.x.npc = "center") +
  stat_regline_equation(aes(group = 1), label.y = 0.5, label.x.npc = "center")

ggpar(q, xscale = "log10", yscale = "log10")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

And as a reference here is the vanilla `ggplot2` way, where instead of using the `group` aes I made `color` a local aes of the `geom_point` only and where I use `ggpubr` only to add the regline equation and correlation coefficient:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ARAL_R <- iris[3:5]
names(ARAL_R) <- c("Intl1", "Sul1", "Core")

ggplot(
  ARAL_R,
  aes(Intl1, Sul1),
) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "black") +
  geom_point(aes(color = Core)) +
  stat_cor(label.y = 1, label.x.npc = "center") +
  stat_regline_equation(label.y = 0.5, label.x.npc = "center") +
  labs(x = "Intl1 (copies/g)", y = "Sul1 (copies/g)") +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10()
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]